# Honours Project Feedback (Video Game Audio)

Tags: honours, video-games, sound-design, student, gameaudio

Hi There, I have been creating and implementing audio into the Unity 3D game engine for my Honours Project at University. I was wondering if anyone with experience in the Video Game Audio field could give me feedback on this project that I could include in my Honours Dissertation. 
The game is based on the Desktop platform and a MacOS/Windows Build of the game can be created.

Any replies are appreciated thanks.

** Update **

MacOS Build: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70495486/MacBuild.zip

Windows Build: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70495486/WindowsBuild.zip

Comment: Hi!  I'm not in game audio, but I thought I'd mention that if you posted a sample of what you wanted evaluated you might be more likely to get a response.  Getting feedback is hard, those who are qualified for such a responsibility are often very busy so try to make it as easy as possible to offer advice =)  Also, like I said, I'm not in game audio but I'm a musician with a good ear so perhaps I can help out in the absence of a real "pro".  Post what you have and I'll let you know what I think.


Comment: I'm also a video game fanatic, for what it's worth.

Comment: That would be great. I have uploaded a Mac Build of the game that you can download.